# Unable to use a aws automl model for batch transform job via aws sdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use a model from an sagemaker automl experiment for a batch transform job for inference. I am not sure if this approach is even correct using SKLearnModel but here is the code and the error:

```
    xgb = SKLearnModel(model_data='model-16003',
                      image=docker_uri,
                      entry_point='sagemaker_serve.py',
                      py_version='py_3',
                      role=role)

    xgb_transformer = xgb.transformer(instance_count,
                                    instance_type,
                                    strategy=strategy,
                                    accept='text/csv',
                                    output_path=output_path,
                                    max_payload=max_payload,
                                    max_concurrent_transforms=max_concurrent_transforms)

    xgb_transformer.transform(input_path,
                             content_type='text/csv',
                             compression_type='Gzip',
                             split_type='Line')

error: No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
```

Am I close or is this the wrong path? Any advise is appreciated!